# Depending on which div href one clicks on one page, loads a different section of a slider on the second page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

One page has a slider containing some divs. 
Another page has a bunch of divs.
How do I make it so that, when I click a certain div on the first page, 
it links the user to the corresponding slider div? Right now, everything starts "ContentBox1." I also have it initialized with it's css being "left: 0;"

HTML of Slider page:

```
<div id="Content">
            <div id="ContentBox1" class="active">
            <div id="ContentBox2" ></div>
            <div id="ContentBox3" ></div>
            <div id="ContentBox4" ></div>
        </div>
```

Here's Slider JS - Operates on click of a separate menu arrow div:

```
var $target = $($('.active').next());

                $('.active').each(function (index, self) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.removeClass('active').animate({ left: -($this.width()) }, 750);
                });

                $target.addClass('active').css({ left: ($target.width()) }).animate({ left: 0 }, 500);
```

Comment: Add something to the href, like say a hash ?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do in pure CSS.  Not sure how to do it with jQuery though.

Linking page

```
<a href="/foo#ContentBox1">
```

Linked page

```
<div id="ContentBox1">
```

CSS of linked page

```
div { transition: left 1s; }
div:target { left: 100px; }
```